# How do you say this? $r(v|W)=(d(v,w_{1}),d(v,w_{2}),\dots ,d(v,w_{k}))$

Tags: graph-theory, notation, terminology

How do you say this?
$$r(v|W)=(d(v,w_{1}),d(v,w_{2}),\dots ,d(v,w_{k}))$$

From the definition part of Wikipedia's ["Metric dimension (Graph Theory)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_dimension_(graph_theory)#Detailed_definition) entry.

Comment: According to the article you've linked this is the representation of a vertex with respect to an ordered subset.

Comment: ty, very much. padding to get to 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using natural language I would say this as "the representation $r$ of $v$ with respect to $W$ is the $k$-tuple of distances from $v$ to the other vertices of the graph."

Comment: ty, very much. padding to get to 15 characters.